# how to use webview in xaml

Tags: xaml, webview, windows-store-apps

I have tried to embed website using webview but im getting error
here is my XAML code for webview

```
<WebView x:Name="WebView1" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Margin="658.74,197.148,113.963,221.865" Grid.Row="1" UseLayoutRounding="False" d:LayoutRounding="Auto"
             Source="http://www.microsoft.com">
        <WebView.RenderTransform>
            <CompositeTransform Rotation="30" ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1" SkewX="15" SkewY="0" />
        </WebView.RenderTransform>
    </WebView>
```

Comment: What's the error you're getting?

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you just try it without any `RenderTransform`? You could simple load a `WebView` like this:

XAML:

```
 <Grid>
 <WebView x:Name="WebView1" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
 <Button x:Name="LoadWebPage" Content="Navigate" click="NavigateButton_Click">
 </Button>                        
 </Grid>
```

.cs:

```
Uri uri= new ("http://www.microsoft.com");
WebView1.Navigate(uri);
```